# How to detect if selenium initializer driver is headless

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

Let's say I have this code

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

browser=webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', 
                                {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
```

How can I check if the initialized browser is headless or not, programmatically? I mean, if I type
`browser.get_window_size()` I get `{'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}`, if I write `browser.execute_script('return navigator.languages')` it returns `['en-US', 'en']`

What I'm looking for is something like `browser.is_headless()` where I can get if a given browser is headless or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless
```

Will return **True**, if `--headless` argument is set into `ChomeOptions()`, otherwise, will return **False**.

Comment: But that is if you have access to the options set from ChromeOptions(). What I require is getting that information from the browser initialized

Comment: For what I saw, there's no attribute that stores the options used while creating the browser instance

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox (tested on Firefox 106):

```py
if driver.caps.get("moz:headless", False):
     print("Firefox is headless")
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the official [Selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options.headless)

`options.headless`

should return whether headless is set or not